# Accept a button press without needing to press enter after

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi

I am working on a soundboard to use as a preset intercom.

By pressing a number on the number pad, I play an audio file. When I press it again during the playback, the playback stops. When I choose another sound during another playback, the first playback stops and the other begins.

I have made a beginning of the code.

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()

pressedKey = pygame.key.get_pressed()
int numberKey = for numberKey in pressedKey.split() if numberKey.isdigit()

if (pygame.key.get_focused() == True):
    if (pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True):
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()

    pygame.mixer.music.load(numberKey + '.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
        continue
```

Every time I push a button in the console, I need to press enter after pressing the button.

Comment: So what is the question? This sounds like a great project and I would love to help however I cannot do so without more information.

Comment: EDIT: I forgot to put the question in the topic... Oops... Now every time when I push a button in the console when I run it, I need to press enter after pressing the button. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use an event loop to get the key inputs. This will constantly detect key presses and not require enter.

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            key = event.key
```

This code will set whatever key was last pressed to the 'key' variable. From there, you have everything else you need.